# Dot Net Database driven Data annotation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have numbers of model in .net core web API  and I save all model properties in database now when post request to action method then it should validate those property on the base of database store annotation.

And I didn't want to write hard coded annotation on each and every property. There should be generic class or method that add different data annotation after load from the database at run time and validate model on base of database properties. Is there any way to resolve it.

**Remember:** I did't use like this:

```
public class UserAddress
{   
    [Required] // this is data annotation and I didn't want to use like this
    public string CityCode { get; set; }
}
```

There are lot of examples to create custom validate class and use Data Annotation on model properties ... but I did not want to use hard coded data annotation but it should be add at run time from database

Instead of that I want to use like this:

```
public class UserAddress
{   
    // this is without data annotation. I want my model should like this
    public string CityCode { get; set; }
}
```

There should be generic code that validate class properties after compare with the database properties and validate on the base of database values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `FluentValidation`. With this you could write `Validator` classes for your models like this :

```
public class UserAddressValidator : AbstractValidator<UserAddress> {
    public UserAddressValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.CityCode ).NotNull();
    }
}
```

You could read more at official docs : https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html

**EDIT**

There is an example on how to move rules to XML : http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/05/16/loading-c-mvc-net-data-annotation-attributes-from-xml-form-validation/

You could implement something like this to get validation rules from db, still, i think that strongly-typed declarations from initial answer are better

Comment: But I did't want to pass hard code properties like this RuleFor(x => x.CityCode ).NotNull();

Comment: This properties should come from database and according to database it should define rules and this method should be generic enough that every model can use it...

Comment: I thought you dont want to mess Entity classes with anotations, not avoid validation at all . Do you mean that you want to store validation rules in DB or smthn like that?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I don't want to mess my model with hard coded annotation. beside this i want generic solution...

Comment: yes i already tried the article example in above link but the most of things are depreciated like  private static Validators _validatorLib; we can not create object Validators because it is a static class and also number of things are not available in .Net core